# libwaffle-1.so.o: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mesa

I have Ubuntu 16.04 OS and am trying to perform tests on piglit. I have a Fermi GPU (GE4 GTX 480).

This is the error I receive. Could you please guide? 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C0LdDzbXxp6dcHuAMivt7MYjRHU3OXe4

Comment: I don't know anything about `piglit`, but `libwaffle-1.so.0` is provided by the `libwaffle-1-0` package

Comment: I had not installed libwaffle-1.0 package but libwaffle-dev instead. Worked when I installed libwaffle-1.0 using sudo apt-get install libwaffle-1-0. Thanks!